# What material is this kitchen countertop

Tags: kitchens, countertops

I just bought a house and the kitchen countertop has some scratches (no deep, you don't feel them with your hand) and glass stains. I'd like to know what material is in order to know if/how I can fix it. Thank you! The last picture es underneath.

[image: Kitchen countertop]

[image: kitchen countertop]

[image: stain countertop]

[image: Kitchen countertop underneath]

Comment: Do you need to know the material or simply how to fix it? If you're asking how to fix it, then please [edit] your question to actually ask that...

Comment: Can't tell the material from here. It could be laminate surface, or any if multiple solid materials. Getting a look at the underside of the counter would at least help us confirm or eliminate laminate.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question - to me it looks like it could be a solid-surface countertop, especially with that side view showing what looks like layers that have been bonded together.  There are many different brands (with Corian being one of the more popular ones in the USA).  To get a better idea, if you have a picture of what it looks like from underneath, we can probably have a better idea since countertop materials are manufactured differently depending on the material, and the bottom view can give additional clues.

I don't see any evidence of staining that you referred to in your question, so can't answer to that repair.  To answer your inevitable followup question about the scratches - if those scratches are shallow, then it's very likely they can be mostly polished/sanded out.  But it takes a good touch and experience to do it well.  So depending on what you want it to look like in the end, it might be worth your money to have a solid surface installer refinish the surface.  With luck, it'll look like new with all of the scratches gone.

Comment: There's a new product (in UK at least) which is like a laminate that fits straight over damaged surfaces like this, just on the market. Pre-empting the next question..!